# Unexpected type. Required variable, found value

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I don't understand why this code is could not be compiled:

```
public class Fibonacci 
{
    static final int MAX_INDEX =10;    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int lo = 1;
        int hi = 1;
        String mark;        
        System.out.println("1: " + lo);        
        for (int i=2;i<MAX_INDEX; i++)
        { 
            if ((hi%2)=0)
            mark="*";            
              else
            mark="";
            System.out.println(i+": "+hi + mark);
            hi=lo+hi;
            lo=hi-lo;            
        }   
    }   
}
```

In NetBeans IDE i have an error:

Unexpected type. Required variable, found value.

```
if ((hi%2)=0)
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. The if statement is expecting something that may return a boolean, it is rather getting a value of 0 as you are assigning (hi%2) to 0. Use a conditional operator like `==`, `>=` or `<=` to get expected results.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is the assignment operator. You meant to use the **equality check** operator, `==`:

```
if ((hi%2) == 0)
// Here ---^
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with '=='.
Instead of giving like this `if ((hi%2)=0)` give like this `if ((hi%2)==0)`.